# Making a row clickable to take you to a link

Tags: php, phpbb3

I've made some CSS modifications to it already and now I need to make one programming modification.  I'm a C# guy so this PHP is throwing me a little curve ball.

Here is the part I would like to modify:

```
<li class="row">
            <!-- EVENT forumlist_body_forum_row_prepend -->
            <dl class="icon {forumrow.FORUM_IMG_STYLE}">
                <dt title="{forumrow.FORUM_FOLDER_IMG_ALT}">
                    <!-- IF forumrow.FORUM_IMAGE --><div class="forum-image">{forumrow.FORUM_IMAGE}</div><!-- ENDIF -->
                    <a href="{forumrow.U_VIEWFORUM}" class="icon-link"></a>

                    <!-- IF .forumrow.subforum and forumrow.S_LIST_SUBFORUMS -->
                    <div class="dropdown-container dropdown-button-control">
                        <span title="{forumrow.L_SUBFORUM_STR}" class="dropdown-trigger"></span>
                        <div class="dropdown hidden">
                            <div class="dropdown-contents">
                            <!-- EVENT forumlist_body_subforums_before -->
                            <strong>{forumrow.L_SUBFORUM_STR}{L_COLON}</strong>
                            <!-- BEGIN subforum -->
                                <a href="{forumrow.subforum.U_SUBFORUM}" class="subforum<!-- IF forumrow.subforum.S_UNREAD --> unread<!-- ELSE --> read<!-- ENDIF -->" title="<!-- IF forumrow.subforum.UNREAD -->{L_UNREAD_POSTS}<!-- ELSE -->{L_NO_UNREAD_POSTS}<!-- ENDIF -->">{forumrow.subforum.SUBFORUM_NAME}</a>
                            <!-- END subforum -->
                            <!-- EVENT forumlist_body_subforums_after -->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- ENDIF -->
                    <div class="list-inner">
                        <a href="{forumrow.U_VIEWFORUM}" class="forumtitle">{forumrow.FORUM_NAME}</a>
                        <span class="forum-description">{forumrow.FORUM_DESC}</span>
                        <!-- IF forumrow.MODERATORS -->
                            <!--<br /><span class="forum-moderators"><strong>{forumrow.L_MODERATOR_STR}{L_COLON}</strong> {forumrow.MODERATORS}</span>-->
                        <!-- ENDIF -->
                    </div>
                </dt>

                <!-- IF forumrow.CLICKS -->
                    <dd class="redirect"><span>{L_REDIRECTS}{L_COLON} {forumrow.CLICKS}</span></dd>
                <!-- ELSEIF not forumrow.S_IS_LINK -->
                    <dd class="forum-stats<!-- IF forumrow.S_UNREAD_FORUM --> unread<!-- ENDIF -->"><span>
                        <!-- IF forumrow.LAST_POST_TIME -->(<dfn>{L_TOPICS}{L_COLON}</dfn> {forumrow.TOPICS} | <dfn>{L_POSTS}{L_COLON}</dfn>{forumrow.POSTS})
                        <!-- IF not S_IS_BOT --><a href="{forumrow.U_LAST_POST}" title="<!-- IF forumrow.S_UNREAD_FORUM -->{L_UNREAD_POSTS}<!-- ELSE -->{L_NO_UNREAD_POSTS}<!-- ENDIF -->">{LAST_POST_IMG}</a><!-- ENDIF --><!-- ELSE -->{L_NO_POSTS}<!-- ENDIF -->
                        <!-- EVENT forumlist_body_last_post_title_prepend -->
                    </span></dd>

                    <dd class="mcp-status"><span>
                        <!-- IF forumrow.U_UNAPPROVED_TOPICS -->
                            <a href="{forumrow.U_UNAPPROVED_TOPICS}">{UNAPPROVED_IMG}</a>
                        <!-- ELSEIF forumrow.U_UNAPPROVED_POSTS -->
                            <a href="{forumrow.U_UNAPPROVED_POSTS}">{UNAPPROVED_POST_IMG}</a>
                        <!-- ENDIF -->
                        </span>
                    </dd>
                <!-- ENDIF -->
            </dl>
            <!-- EVENT forumlist_body_forum_row_append -->
        </li>
```

I would like if the `"row"` is clicked for it to take you to the forum.  Right now only if the title/header is clicked will it take you to the forum.

Which I believe is this line:

```
<a href="{forumrow.U_VIEWFORUM}" class="icon-link"></a>
```

Here is a demo of how the default template works:

https://www.phpbb.com/customise/db/style/pbtech/demo/3.1
The only difference I have made from the demo is those `forum "blocks"` are now changed to take up `100% width` instead of `33.3%`.  I'd like it so if you click anywhere on the forum "block/row" it takes you to the forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be achieved with PHP. It could be achieved with a small JavaScript snippet on the front end.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function(){

    $("li.row").click( function(){
        var anchor = $(this).find("a:first");
        anchor.trigger("click"); // OR
        window.location = anchor.attr("href");
    });
});
</script>
```

What this does is attaches an event handler to any clicks on `li.row`. It finds the link within and either triggers click to it, or uses its `href` property to change browser window location URL.

This requires a JavaScript library called jQuery which appears to already be in use on your demo template. The code block above would need to be included BELOW the `<script>` include tag for jQuery.

Comment: Alright, I can do it in jQuery.  Just wanted to make sure there wasn't some super clean way to do it in PHP.  Since li.row's "could" be used elsewhere I assume I should add my own personal class and run this jQuery off that class.

Comment: If you wanted to, you could also change in the PHP with pure native JavaScript: `<li class="row" onclick="javascript:window.location='{forumrow.U_VIEWFORUM}';">`

Comment: Hrm I like that, that way it only affects those forum headers.  I did try the above jQuery, but could not get the anchor.trigger to work.  The window.location worked however.

Comment: Alway avoid throwing a framework like JQuery to your page for a simple action. :-)

Comment: @ErwinMoller agreed 100%! but the framework is already there in this case :}